# Failed to perform checkout on agent

Tags: teamcity

> Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8517307457314531623.bat
>   -c credential.helper= -c credential.helper=C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/credHelper4649196994804332385.bat
>   reset --hard 1df124bae56fa97bbfd0c144a85fa80cacd4fedb' command failed.

Please note, I have tried adding `teamcity.git.use.native.ssh=true` in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties file at the end of file. Also tried adding it in "Configuration Parameters" but no avail. Any guidance will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Build Log

> Build 'BUILD_NAME :: Build' #10 Started 2017-09-06 04:17:09 on
>   'AGENT_NAME' by 'Git' Finished 2017-09-06 04:17:24 with status FAILURE
>   'Error while applying patch' VCS revisions:
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy' (Git):
>   6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f (branch 'refs/heads/deploy')
>   TeamCity URL
>   http://SERVER:PORT/viewLog.html?buildId=258&buildTypeId=BUILD_NAME_Build
>   TeamCity server version is 2017.1 (build 46533), timezone: UTC
>
> [04:17:03]E: bt9 (20s) [04:17:03]i: TeamCity server version is 2017.1
>   (build 46533) [04:17:03] : Finalize build settings [04:17:04] : The
>   build is removed from the queue to be prepared for the start
>   [04:17:04] : Collecting changes in 1 VCS root (4s) [04:17:04] :
>   [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details [04:17:04] :
>   [VCS Root details]
>   "https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy"
>   {instance id=27, parent internal id=9, parent
>   id=BUILD_NAME_HttpsUSERNAMEBitbucketOrgPROJECTGitRefs, description:
>   "https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy"}
>   [04:17:08]i:   [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Detecting changes in
>   VCS root
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy' (used
>   in 'Build') [04:17:08]i:   [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Will
>   collect changes for
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy'
>   starting from revision 6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f
>   [04:17:08] :   [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Compute revision for
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy'
>   [04:17:08] :       [Compute revision for
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy'] Upper
>   limit revision: 6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f
>   [04:17:08]i:       [Compute revision for
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy']
>   MaxModId = 6006 [04:17:08] :       [Compute revision for
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy'] Latest
>   commit attached to build configuration:
>   6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f [04:17:08] :      [Compute
>   revision for
>   'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy']
>   Computed revision: 6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f [04:17:08]
>   : Starting the build on the agent AGENT_NAME [04:17:09]i: Agent time
>   zone: UTC [04:17:10]i: Agent is running under JRE: 1.8.0_121-b13
>   [04:17:10] : Clearing temporary directory:
>   C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp [04:17:10] : Publishing internal
>   artifacts [04:17:10] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1
>   file using [WebPublisher] [04:17:10] :     [Publishing internal
>   artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
>   [04:17:10] : Using vcs information from agent file:
>   40fe536e1ba26e7d.xml [04:17:10] : Checkout directory:
>   C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d [04:17:10]E: Updating
>   sources: auto checkout (on agent) (13s) [04:17:10] :   [Updating
>   sources] Will use agent side checkout [04:17:10] :     [Updating sources]
>   VCS Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy
>   (13s) [04:17:10] :         [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   revision: 6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f [04:17:10] :        [VCS
>   Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   Git version: 2.13.0.0 [04:17:10] :         [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref [04:17:10] :       [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass6391275250942021006.bat
>   -c credential.helper= ls-remote origin [04:17:11] :        [VCS Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref refs/remotes/origin/deploy [04:17:11]
>   :      [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref refs/heads/deploy [04:17:11] :         [VCS
>   Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass4132618148202213556.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/deploy:refs/heads/deploy (2s) [04:17:13] :           [[C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass4132618148202213556.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/deploy:refs/heads/deploy] remote: Counting objects: 1, done.         [04:17:13] :
>   [[C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass4132618148202213556.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/deploy:refs/heads/deploy] remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)         [04:17:13] :
>   [[C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass4132618148202213556.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/deploy:refs/heads/deploy] From https://bitbucket.org/PROJECT [04:17:13] :
>   [[C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass4132618148202213556.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/deploy:refs/heads/deploy]  * [new branch]      deploy     -> deploy [04:17:13] :             [[C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass4132618148202213556.bat
>   -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/deploy:refs/heads/deploy]  * [new branch]      deploy     -> origin/deploy [04:17:13] :      [VCS Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" log -n1 --pretty=format:%H%x20%s
>   6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f -- [04:17:13] :       [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config remote.origin.url [04:17:13] :       [VCS
>   Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-775EA635.git]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" pack-refs --all [04:17:13] :        [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config core.sparseCheckout true [04:17:13] :
>   [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref [04:17:13] :       [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8692935477830272422.bat
>   -c credential.helper= ls-remote origin [04:17:14] :        [VCS Root: https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref refs/remotes/origin/deploy [04:17:14]
>   :      [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" log -n1 --pretty=format:%H%x20%s
>   6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f -- [04:17:14] :       [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" branch [04:17:14] :         [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" update-ref refs/heads/deploy
>   6d6ef41657179c8e25b128c479d570b0320e368f [04:17:14] :      [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy]
>   [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\40fe536e1ba26e7d]: "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass3509070227318612601.bat
>   -c credential.helper= -c credential.helper=C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/credHelper7927651800956395094.bat
>   checkout -q -f deploy [04:17:24] :         [VCS Root:
>   https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/PROJECT.git#refs/heads/deploy] fatal:
>   cannot create directory at
>   'node_modules/ep_etherpad-lite/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point/node_modules/number-is-nan':
>   Filename too long 
>   [04:17:24]E:   [Updating sources] Failed to perform
>   checkout on agent: '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.askpass=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass3509070227318612601.bat
>   -c credential.helper= -c credential.helper=C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/credHelper7927651800956395094.bat
>   checkout -q -f deploy' command failed. exit code: 128 stderr: fatal:
>   cannot create directory at
>   'node_modules/ep_etherpad-lite/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point/node_modules/number-is-nan':
>   Filename too long 
>   [04:17:24] : Publishing internal artifacts
>   [04:17:24] :   [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using
>   [WebPublisher] 
>   [04:17:24] :   [Publishing internal artifacts]
>   Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher] 
>   [04:17:24] : Build
>   failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
>   [04:17:25] : Build finished

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the TeamCity version? How your VCS root is configured? Can you show the whole log?

Comment: Hi Boris, added build log. TeamCity Version is "TeamCity Professional 2017.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Filename too long` was indeed the problem but being an etherpad project I was not in position to change the plugin name or path so I 
 change my `workDir` to be smallest possible in `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties` i.e. `workDir=C\:\\w` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the log I see that the problem is with creating too long path. On Windows maximum path length is 260 characters. I suggest reducing the nesting of directories in your project structure:

`node_modules/ep_etherpad-lite/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point/node_modules/number-is-nan`